# how to share a link to facebook, twitter and etc?

Tags: android, mime-types

Firstly, My app's function is to read the article. When a user reads the article and he want to share the article to facebook or others, I cannot find link/ hyperlink from the type.

Here is my sharing function

```
private void shareIt() {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

The thing that i want is the share function when using computer to read the article and got the share button. In the sharing medium, it will appear as the content of the article instead of plain text.

So, how to edit the code so that i can share a link?

Do guide me on Manifest.xml, i am not sure interfilter need to add which category too.

Second, i saw the sharing list, the built-in list not so good for me because i want those those facebook, sina, twitter instead of google, gmail, bluetooth, line or messaging.

So, how to implement the list of sharing through java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be like this

```
sharebtn = new Custom_ButtonField(share, shareactive, shareactive) {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                if (Config_GlobalFunction.isConnected()) {
                    String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
                    String APPLICATION_ID = "153555168010272";
                    String APPLICATION_SECRET = "354f91a79c8fe5a8de9d65b55ef9aa1b";
                    String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.USER_DATA_PERMISSIONS;
                    ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(
                            NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET,
                            PERMISSIONS);
                    Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);
                    try {
                        User user = fb.getCurrentUser();
                        user.publishStatus(Config_GlobalFunction.sharelink
                                + newsid);
                    } catch (FacebookException e) {
                    }
                } else
                    Config_GlobalFunction.Message(
                            Config_GlobalFunction.nosharenews, 1);
                return true;
            }
        };
        add(sharebtn);
```

Precondition: you must import BB facebook sdk.